# JS img click function is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make sure that when I click an image

```
<div id="getImage" class="gallery_grid_item md-card-content">
<img onClick="handleImage()" src ="img.png">
</div>

<div id="holdImage">
</div>
```

then it is placed into another div

```
function handleImage() {
        var $img = $("#getImage").children("img");
        $("#holdImage").append($img);
    }
```

However, I've double and triple checked this but the function still shows as undefined in the console?

What's going on here?

Comment: You forgot the closing `"` in `<img onClick="handleImage() src ="img.png">`

Comment: also `"getImage"` implies your targetting an element. You probably forgot to add the `id` or `class` specifier (`#`, or `.` )

Comment: Also `getImage` should  be prefix with `#` or `.`...

Comment: @Mamun I've added # but unfortunately the quote was just a typo on here. still no luck

Comment: Could add all the relevant HTML as part of the question....

Comment: @Mamun I have added now

Comment: You are looking for `<getImage>` elements

Comment: function is not defined? Did you stick it inside a document ready call? Sounds like the method is not in global scope

Comment: @TomN. check my answer i fixed all errors, and it's working now

Comment: @DreamHunter-hashADH do you think it's because I have the html coming back from inline of a JS function return like so: ```function appendSomeItems(url, id, name, style) {
            return '<div><div class="md-card">         <div id="getImage" class="gallery_grid_item md-card-content"> <img onClick="handleImage()" class ="uk-align-center" ></a>                               <div class="gallery_grid_image_caption">                                   <span class="gallery_image_title uk-text-truncate">' + name + '</span> <span>' + style + '</span> </div></div></div></div>';
        }```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was caused by something that you missed and I correct all of that

1. `$("getImage")` is replaced by `$("#getImage")` ,(you missed one `#` here)
2. `onClick="handleImage()` is replaced by `onClick="handleImage()"` ,(you missed one 
   `"` here)
3. `var $img` is replaced by `var img` (you don't  need to have a `$` sign to declare a variable in js.

```js
function handleImage() {
            var img = $("#getImage").children("img");
            $("#holdImage").append(img);
        }
```

```css
#getImage{
width:50px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #000;
}
#getImage>img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#holdImage{
width:100px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="getImage" class="gallery_grid_item md-card-content">
    <img onClick="handleImage()" src ="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/img_01.jpg" >
 </div>

    <div id="holdImage">
    </div>
```

Comment: Would it be causing problems for me if that html is inline in a JS function like this: ```function appendSomeItems(url, id, name, style) {
            return '<div><div class="md-card md-card-hover">         <div id="getImage" class="gallery_grid_item md-card-content"> <img onClick="handleImage()" class ="uk-align-center"></a>                               <div class="gallery_grid_image_caption">                                   <span class="gallery_image_title uk-text-truncate">' + name + '</span> <span>' + style + '</span> </div></div></div></div>';
        }```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the quotes on onClick="..." so it may be looking for a function named "handleImage() src="

Comment: Ok so that was actually a typo on here, but I do have quotes added in my code. Also I added a '#' to my getImage  but still no luck

Comment: Why are you naming a variable '$img'? I would be wary of using the jQuery operator ($) in a variable name. Have you tried changing that variable name?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the src attribute
`<img onClick="handleImage()" src ="img.png">`